# How to find $\lfloor 1/\sqrt{1}+1/\sqrt{2}+\dots+1/\sqrt{100}\rfloor $ without a calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$
\left\lfloor\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +\dots+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{100}}\right\rfloor =\,?
$$

I rationalized the denominator and then I think I should somehow group the numbers, but i don't know how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "with whole numbers?" The answer is not a whole number.

Oh, just realized that the brackets may mean floor.

Comment: Does $[\cdot ]$ denote the greatest-integer / floor function (aka Gauß bracket)?

Comment: [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+from+1+to+100+of+1%2Fsqrt%28x%29) says the sum is $\approx 18.59$; do with the square brackets what you will.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes the `[]` structure denotes the floor function. Say `x` is `3.14` than `[x]` is `3`.

Comment: @vadim123 Thanks for your response but I also need a mathematical proof. :)

Comment: But for an easy lower bound ($\,3\,$) , I can't see how to get the upper one without getting into boring and messy numerical estimations...

Comment: @DonAntonio I understand what you are saying about those numerical estimation. However, there is an entire chapter with these kinds of exercises and this makes me think that there is should be some kind of method to solve the exercise.

Comment: And that chapter deals...with what, @DoraBenzo ?!

Comment: @DonAntonio The integer (floor) and fractional part of a Real (included in R) number

Comment: @DoraBenzo What book are you using?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan  my teacher send it on email...RMT is the pdf's name

Comment: @DoraBenzo Would it be possible for you to post the PDF?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing the square brackets to unambiguous floor-function notation.  Square brackets used to be used because that's what was available.  Things have been different for the past quarter of a century or so.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Besides the fact that the book is in Romanian, as I said I got it from school so there may be  license issue.Sorry.

Comment: See also this question: [How to prove the inequality $2\sqrt{n + 1} − 2 \le 1 +\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}+\frac 1 {\sqrt 3}+ \dots +\frac 1 {\sqrt n} \le 2\sqrt n − 1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995110/how-to-prove-the-inequality-2-sqrtn-1-%E2%88%92-2-le-1-frac-1-sqrt-2-frac-1) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/995110).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Doing it in 9th grade math is quite a challenge.  But perhaps this would come close.

For any positive number $t$, we have 
$$ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}} > 2 \sqrt{t+1} - 2 \sqrt{t} > \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t+1}}$$

To see the first inequality, note that

$$ \left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}} + 2 \sqrt{t}\right)^2 = \dfrac{1}{t} + 4 + 4 t > 4 + 4 t = (2 \sqrt{t+1})^2$$
Similarly for the second, by looking at $\left(2 \sqrt{t+1} - \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t+1}}\right)^2$.

So $$\eqalign{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \ldots + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{100}}
&> (2 \sqrt{2} - 2 \sqrt{1}) + (2 \sqrt{3} - 2 \sqrt{2}) + \ldots + (2 \sqrt{101} - 2 \sqrt{100})\cr &= 2 \sqrt{101} - 2 > 2 \sqrt{100} - 2 = 18\cr}$$ 
while
$$\eqalign{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \ldots + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{100}}
&< 1 + (2 \sqrt{2} - 2 \sqrt{1}) + \ldots + (2 \sqrt{100} - 2 \sqrt{99})\cr
& = 1 + 20 - 2 = 19\cr}$$

Comment: It seem that your solution solves my problem. However I was wondering what was your process of thinking which led to that `1/sqrt(t) + 2*sqrt(t)` assumption. I would have never guessed it. Thanks again!

Comment: The idea came from the integral...

Comment: ok...I'm thinking at my theacher..he may asks me why I solved in this way the problem.

Comment: Why not be honest and tell him that you got help here?

Answer (score 5):

You can get a lower bound by $$\sum_{i=1}^{100}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}> \int_1^{101}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{101}-2\approx 18.10$$

You can get an upper bound by $$\sum_{i=1}^{100}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}< \int_0^{100}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=20$$

We can refine that upper bound by replacing $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$ with $1$, which replaces 20 with 19.  Hence the desired sum lies between 18 and 19, with floor 18.

Comment: Thanks again for your involvement. The trickier part is that the exercise should be resolved using 9th grade math. This means that no mathematical analysis concept should be used.

Comment: Very Nice Solution vadim123, Using Integration.