# Evaluate the following series using elementary methods.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$\frac{1} {\sqrt 1} + \frac{1} {\sqrt2} + \dots + \frac{1} {\sqrt{ 100}}$

Just bear in mind that I'm going to say the solution to a person of low education. So please provide creative hints or solutions. I don't want to use derivatives or other limit-related stuff. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:Sorry for posting a duplicate question but I have another question now.Can you prove that the series above does not have rational answer?

Comment: Then don't tag it with 'calculus'.

Comment: Of low education? Can they use a calculator?

Comment: even with calculus I would say it's difficult, ALI for me

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516846/how-to-find-lfloor-1-sqrt11-sqrt2-dots1-sqrt100-rfloor-without-a?rq=1

Comment: Is this question really a duplicate? The linked question asks for the greatest integer of the sum, while this question apparently asks for the exact answer. Also, the recent edit adds another question. Shall we reopen this question?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I would love it if you could please reopen it. At least until the second question has been answered.Thanks.

Comment: I, with two others, have already voted to reopen this question. Two more such votes are needed. Adding more to the question about what you have tried, or clarifying that you are asking about the exact sum and not its greatest integer part, would help to get those votes. You should edit your question further.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks for the respond.What do you propose exactly?I mean what additional information should I add?I hope I could convince this Mr/Mrs Jack D'Aurizio to reopen the question.Sounds like some people are just lurking around in the questions section waiting for somebody to post a duplicate and there you go,they close it before double-checking it ever again.Ridiculus ...

Comment: I already mentioned two things you could add: (1) what you have tried, (2) that you are asking about the exact sum and not its greatest integer part. If all this fails, you could delete this question and ask another question about the rationality of the sum. I also recommend that you not diss the people who have put a lot of work into this site: that is not likely to gain you sympathy.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks again for your fast respond.BTW I'm not looking for anybody to sympathize with me and all I'm saying is what it looks like.I'll try a bit more tomorrow and will update the question again according to your sayings.Thanks again.